# Checking Each Item in Array for Substring

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm building an array from the output of a command.  Each line of output is one item in the array.  I'm then iterating through each item and testing for a certain sequence of characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t LST < <(#read in single or multiline output from command)
d="sometext:123"
SUBS=":$(echo $d | cut -d':' -f 2)"
for i in "${LST[@]}"
do
  if [[ $i == *"$SUBS"* ]]
  then
    #save $i in new variable
    exit 0
  fi
done
echo "no match"
exit 1
```

The problem appears to have something to do with the $SUBS variable.  If I echo $SUBS based on the above, it outputs :123, but the comparison apparently returns false.  If I populate SUBS this way:

```
SUBS=":123"
```

The comparison appears to work as expected.  With any other method of populating $SUBS I've tried, the comparison seems to return false.  The issue is, $d might not contain ":123" exactly.  It could be ":456" or some other number preceded by a :.

Comment: works here; what's the she-bang line? If it's /bin/sh, is /bin/sh dash instead of bash? (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: it's #!/bin/bash

Comment: It might be worth adding that my system is RHEL 6.9.

Comment: @ilkkachu in my first attempt, I was finding the index of the : character, subtracting 1 from it to include the : and then getting the substring like this: `SUBS=${d:$IndexOfColonMinusOne}`  This was also returning false when it would hit the comparison.

Comment: It may be helpful to include a sample run with `set -x` enabled.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I think that helped.  In the output, I found something similar to /bin/bash = /bin/ksh which prompted me to google something else.  Changing my if statement to `if test "${i#*$SUBS}" == "$i"` appears to make it work.  I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: Curious how you're ending up running ksh while explicitly invoking bash.

Comment: Wish I could say, but that's above my pay grade.  I'll need to check with the sysadmin for future reference.

Comment: err, what, `/bin/bash = /bin/ksh`?? My ksh doesn't know `readarray`, but the rest of the script works fine with it.

Comment: If it helps, here's the output of set -x where it shows: `+++ history_to_syslog
+++ defshell=/bin/bash
+++ '[' /bin/bash = /bin/ksh ']'
+++ declare cmd`  For what it's worth, I think the issue is unrelated to ksh.  It seems bash wasn't evaluating the [[ ]] as expected (according to the internet anyway), I guess.  set -x exposes this with the original code: `+ [[ sometext:123 == ** ]]` whereas using `if test "${i#*$SUBS}" == "$i"` results in `+ test 'sometext:123' == 'sometext:123'`.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jeff Schaller's suggestion to use set -x (see comments above), in the output, I found a line similar to /bin/bash = /bin/ksh.  This prompted me to google what I was searching for with ksh instead of bash.  I came across this post:

[how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)

According to the accepted answer, I changed my if line to:

```
if test "${i#*$SUBS}" == "$i"
```

This appears to resolve the issue I was experiencing.